# What Lucene analyzer should I use if I want to allow all characters in a string?

Tags: java, string, search, lucene

I'm creating a dictionary app that searches both a word and its definition (two separate `Field`s). However, using a `StandardAnalyzer`, no search results are returned when the search string contains whitespace or special characters.

For example, in my dummy dictionary data, searching "lorem" searches all words that have "lorem" in their definitions, but searching for "lorem ipsum" returns nothing, even though most of my dummy words have a lorem ipsum in the definition.

Also, searching for words like "make-believe" only returns results when typing "make," but as soon as I include the dash, nothing is returned.

I want to include characters like whitespace, dashes, commas, whatever--basically everything in the search string (except perhaps the nonsense words like "and," "at," "by," etc.), but what analyzer should I use? I've tried `PatternAnalyzer` and supplied `.+` as the `Pattern` to look for but typing even just a single letter returns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stuck with a `StandardAnalyzer` since there doesn't seem to be an alternative. What I did is tokenize the string via a regex that captures non-word characters, combine them in an AND `BooleanQuery`, and combine the query for the two `Field`s in another OR `BooleanQuery`.

In my code below, `entry` is the word, `description` is the definition, and `s` is the search string as a `CharSequence`.

```
BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery();
BooleanQuery entryBQ = new BooleanQuery();
BooleanQuery descriptionBQ = new BooleanQuery();
String[] tokens = String.valueOf(s).split("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
for (String token : tokens) {
    if (token.isEmpty()) continue;
    entryBQ.add(new WildcardQuery(new Term("entry", token + "*")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    descriptionBQ.add(new WildcardQuery(new Term("description", token + "*")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
}
bq.add(entryBQ, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
bq.add(descriptionBQ, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(10, true);
is.search(bq, collector);
```

This is horrendously slow in my Android app right now but I can optimize it later. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously think about writing your own analyzer, but I know that will be harder than using an existing analyzer.